# solving a type of integral equation by series

Tags: integration

given the integral equation

$$ g(s)=s \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(st)f(t)dt $$

is it possible to solve it with the series

$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a(n)}{K(n+1)}x^{n} $$

with $ K(n+1)= \int_{0}^{\infty}k(t)t^{n}dt $

and provided that the function $ g(s) $ has a expansion in powers of $ 1/s $

$$ g(s)= a(0) +a(1)/s  +a(2)/s^{2}+... $$ ??

at least as an asympttoic solution